# How to unlink the excel file after download in cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, excel, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am doing an excel plugin for my project ,i want to unlink that excel file after the completion of download by the user or cancel by the user in the popup showing for the download.

I have tried the unlink code to getting things done ,but as there is the response ,i am slightly confuse how to make it.
Below i have attached some part of code .
Any suggestion will highly appreciated.

```html
 $filename = time() . "-ocma-sales-report-" . date("Y-m-d") . ".xlsx"; //'.time() . '-ocma-sales-report-' . date("Y-m-d").'.xls'
                        $objWriter->save("temp_excel/$filename");

                        $filePath = 'temp_excel/' . $filename;
                        $this->response->file($filePath, ['download' => TRUE, 'name' => $filename]);

                        return $this->response;
                        //unlink($filename);

                        exit;
```

Comment: I can't tell you how to do it in CakePHP but PHP provides several tools to generate temporary files and get them removed automatically, from the `tmpfile()` function to the `php://temp` stream wrapper. If you handle temp files yourself you'll have to schedule a clean up process because deletion will fail sooner or later.

Comment: Ok @ÁlvaroGonzález i got it .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileSystem/File class for create, modify and delete file. Also for download file you have to use simple php code because `$this->response->file($filePath, ['download' => TRUE, 'name' => $filename]);`
 is not allowing to so any operation after executing function.

```
ob_clean();

$filePath = 'temp_excel/' . $filename;
$size   = filesize($filePath);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
readfile($filePath);

$file = new \Cake\Filesystem\File($filePath);
$file->delete();
exit();
```

Comment: Can I know where are you from?

Comment: India,odisha  ,bhubaneswar

Comment: hii ,its not working.Below is my code

 $filePath = 'temp_excel/' . $filename;
                        $this->response->file($filePath, ['download' => TRUE, 'name' => $filename]);
                        $file = new \Cake\Filesystem\File($filePath);
                        $file->delete();
                        return $this->response;
                        exit;

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: Ok i am checking .

Comment: yes response not allowing any operation .I noticed .

Comment: I have changes in variable name, so please check it

Comment: Wow ,amazing its working for both the save and cancel .
Thanks  mam a lot .
You made it.
Its quiet easier to do ,rather than using foreach ,i have seen some where in So

Comment: Ok can you please provide me some link so that i can understand the code header() and so on.

I have implemented it  in my project .Its working fine .

want to know in details.

Thank you again.

Comment: Ok i will ;) ;)

Comment: Not all only 5 to 6 :)

Comment: Ok. done .I will follow the above link for more details.

Comment: can you follow me fb and linkedin also.. if you dont mine... :)

Comment: Ya sure ,give me links .

Comment: fine it out by my name

Comment: Yup ,sent  in linkedin.